# Connect to Existing Hive in IntelliJ (using SBT as build)

Tags: intellij-idea, hive, sbt, apache-spark

I have an existing hive on my ubuntu machine. I am just trying to create a table through Apache Spark SQL in hive. I use IntelliJ for development.

My build.sbt is as following

```
name := "TabConnect"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.2.0"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.0"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.2.0"
```

So I have not included hive since I already have hive. Now I just want to create a table in hive using Spark sql. My code is as follows

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object Tabconnect {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "name")

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

    sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Demo (key INT, value STRING)")


  }
}
```

Now where should I add hive dependency since it give me error because it does not recognize hive. I asked at user mailing list , and got the answer that I should copy `hive-site.xml` to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/` but I do not have a Spark directory. Since build.sbt take everything from maven repo or local ivy2 repository.

So where should I copy `hive-site.xml`? So that I can just run this code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to connect to tableau. ;) :) 
So I basically followed these steps :

## On Spark side

1. Download tar file from apche spark site and Untar
2. Follow the below commands for building the spark inside the extracted dir:

   `sbt/sbt package`

   `sbt/sbt  -Phive -Phive-thriftserver assembly`
3. Run one Master and one worker.
4. Start thrift server. No Need to configure since it will internally use Hive MetaStore. It is only if we want remote metastore . Make sure to have configuration file in classpath(hive-site.xml) for remote one.

   `./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh`

5.Check the connectivity from beeline

```
./bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://192.168.56.101:10000​
```

## On tableau Side :

1. Trying connecting from Simba.
   Go to Connect to data -> other databases(ODBC) -> Driver -> Simba Spark ODBC Driver ->
   database is default. And user authentication as my user name of computer (In this case ubuntu VM)

## On part of connecting through intelliJ

1.I included the Spark Jar I build  previously in my lib path. Also added one dependency for jdbc hive driver in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "0.12.0"
```

2. Following is the code I used for creating the table from data on my local machine.

   ```
   import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager}
   import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
   import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD
   import org.apache.spark.sql.hive
   import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

   object ThriftRun {

     def main(args: Array[String]) {

   val driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

   val url = "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default"
   val username = ""
   val password = ""

   // there's probably a better way to do this
   var connection:Connection = null

   try {
     // make the connection
     Class.forName(driver)
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

     // create the statement, and run the select query
     val statement = connection.createStatement()
     val tableName = "patient_external"

     //hive takes a directory of file as path, not a file. data is the directory where the data file resides

     var resultSet = statement.executeQuery("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE patient_external(pid INT, pname STRING, drug STRING," +
       "gender STRING,tot_amt INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION " +
       "'/home/ashu/IdeaProjects/thrift/data'")

     val sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'"
     println("Running: " + sql)

     resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql)

     while ( resultSet.next() ) {
       println(resultSet.getString(1))
     }
   } catch {
     case e => e.printStackTrace
   }
   connection.close()
     }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to connect by doing the following:

1. First ingest csv file or json and save out to file system:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
   import com.databricks.spark.csv._
   val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
   val demo = sqlContext.csvFile("/user/data/csv/demo.csv")
   demo.toJSON.saveAsTextFile("/user/data/json/test”)
   ```
2. Start $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-thirftserver:

   ```
   ./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://radtech.io:7077 --total-executor-cores 2 --driver-class-path --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10001 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host radtech.io
   ```
3. Start tableau session.  Create a connection to thrift server via SparkSQL (Beta) connector.
4. In Tableau add the following to the “Initial SQL”

   ```
   create temporary table test
   using org.apache.spark.sql.json
   options (path '/user/data/json/test/*’);

   cache table test;
   ```

   5. Refresh connection.

Then select “New Custom SQL” and issue something like:

```
select * from test;
```

You will see your table appear.

HTH.

-Todd

Answer (score 0):

copy your hive-site.xml in to the resources folder of your intellij project

Comment: Does this work for you. I copied the file in the resources folder of INteliJ and still im getting the same error.